# My messages are not reaching WhatsApp server in a particular group. Why?

Tags: whatsapp

I'm using WhatsApp since i bought Lumia525 18 months ago. I had many groups like schools, colleges, colleagues and many more. Whereas, from last week my messages are not posting in a particular group but i have following privilege's mentioned below,

1. Changing group name
2. Changing group image

**Below are the case, what I have tried so for?**

1. Left group, and rejoined the group
2. Re-installed WhatsApp almost three times and at last time i didn't restored back the old messages

So, I have mentioned the scenario's that caught me above. Help me to overcome this situation.

Comment: Have you checked with Whatsapp support?

Comment: No, didn't contacted. Thanks for your hint.